# how to do unit testing using junit using java

Tags: java, unit-testing

How we can do PHPUnit testing in wordpress website ? Including theme and plugin everything.

I have setup the phpunit and included wp-load.php file to get all functions and classes access.

Is this correct way ? or There is any better way of doing the Unit Testing in wordpress.

Comment: Why is there java tag ?

Comment: Why is your title about Java and JUnit but your question about PHP?

Comment: Sorry, but this is way too broad. We help with specific questions; not with "explaining everything"?

Comment: You want to unit test php code using java? Or you want to unit test php code with phpunit?